# С# назначить кнопку через ComboBox для элемента

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Здравствуйте, кто может подсказать и показать примерами как бы в роде простую задачку?

Есть три `ComboBox` на 4 пункта:

1. Пункт  <kbd>None</kbd>
2. Пункт  <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>
3. Пункт  <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>
4. Пункт  <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>

и есть три индикатора для каждой кнопки.

Нужно сделать так: если человек выбирает в `ComboBox` для первого индикатора клавишу, например  <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> , тогда первый индикатор будет реагировать только на клавишу  <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> , а если человек выбирает клавишу  <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>  - значить индикатор будет реагировать только на клавишу  <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> , и так далее для остальных 2-х индикаторов и `ComboBox`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: >>есть 3 индикатора для каждой кнопки<< Индикатора три, но реагирует один. Какой смысл? Покажите скрин.

Comment: Я написал один для примера, надо для всех трех индикаторов аналогично как и для первого

Comment: Всё стало понятным)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Перед тем как выполнить соответствие (в вашем случае - нужно каждому индикатору поставить в соответствие состояние клавиши), необходимо продумать архитектуру. Предлагаю внести в проект класс для одного индикатора.

   ```
   public class LedItem {

       public const int NULL        = 0x00;
       public const int CAPS_LOCK   = 0x01;
       public const int NUM_LOCK    = 0x02;
       public const int SCROLL_LOCK = 0x03;

       private int index;
       private int keyCode;

       public LedItem(int index, int keyCode) {
           this.index = index;
           this.keyCode = keyCode;
       }

       public int Index {
           get {
               return this.index;
           }
       }

       public int KeyCode {
           get {
               return this.keyCode;
           }
           set {
               this.keyCode = value;
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. Перед тем как что то выбирать, на старте проекта необходимо сформировать наши индикаторы, например:

   ```
   private LedItem led1 = new LedItem(0, LedItem.NULL);
   ```
3. Вешаем слушателя на ComboBox:

   ```
       int select = cmbButtonState.SelectedIndex;
       switch (select) {
           case 0:
               led1.KeyCode = LedItem.NULL;
               break;
           case 1:
               led1.KeyCode = LedItem.CAPS_LOCK;
               break;
           case 2:
               led1.KeyCode = LedItem.NUM_LOCK;
               break;
           case 3:
               led1.KeyCode = LedItem.SCROLL_LOCK;
               break;
       }
   ```

Слушатель меняет клавишу, за которой следит индикатор. Всё довольно просто.

4. Рисуем результат относительно статусов индикаторов, для этого, можно добавить таймер (если это UI поток), или Thread:

   ```
       private void tmrThread_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           switch (led1.KeyCode) {
               case LedItem.NULL:
                   chkLed.Checked = false;
                   break;
               case LedItem.CAPS_LOCK:
                   chkLed.Checked = KeyService.CapsLockState;
                   break;
               case LedItem.NUM_LOCK:
                   chkLed.Checked = KeyService.NumLockState;
                   break;
               case LedItem.SCROLL_LOCK:
                   chkLed.Checked = KeyService.ScrollLockState;
                   break;
           }
       }
   ```

Для полноты картины прикрепляю исходник проекта.
[Ссылка на архив](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVmigsAHBVBpULXsxqwEkaScl78Lq6fV/view?usp=sharing)

Если вы знакомы с делегатами, я могу намекнуть на то что от switch конструкций можно избавиться) Если не знакомы, можете оставлять всё как есть. Для того чтобы добавить ещё два индикатора, не надо лепить led2, led3... и т.д., достаточно собрать коллекцию List и проходить по ней, индекс индикатора будет в led.Index, код клавиши за которой он следит - led.KeyCode

Comment: А не лучше ли константы заменить на enum?

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @сергейбабий, если один из полученных ответов (или вовсе один ответ) решили ваш вопрос и вы считаете его верным - отметьте его в качестве принятого (галочка напротив ответа), а также, если вы счтаете, что ответ является полезным, то вы можете его пометить полезным (стрелка вверх), вы уже набрали более 15 баллов репутации и такие действия уже могут быть выполнены. За принятый ответ (не являющимся собственным) вы получите +2 балла к репутации. Отмечая ответы в качестве полезного - вы добавляете +10 баллов репутации автору ответа.

Comment: @iluxa1810, лучше и енум и константы выкинуть, и сделать event-ами, но, чем проще - тем лучше для автора. А уже как лучше сделать (и надо ли оно) - он сам решит.

Comment: не могу что то разобраться как мне сделать это со своим кодом https://pastebin.com/uq5VLWgc дело в том что мои индикаторы делаются кодом в трее

Comment: @сергейбабий, Посмотрите класс KeyAPI в моём проекте, и уберите ваш не очень удачный код с хуками. Вы свалили весь код в одну кучу, более того, функции повторяют друг друга... Чем отличается отрисовка индикатора со статусом true от того же индикатора со статусом false? Я вас убеждаю - ничем) То есть, эти два действия может сделать одна функция, которая примет на вход цвет, которым необходимо отрисовать "лампочку" индикатора. В общем, мой совет - используйте абстракцию, у вас же есть целый мир ООП, а вы мыслите функционально...

Comment: @сергейбабий, ваш код для рисования иконки трея ничем не отличается от моего проекта. Что вам мешает перерисовывать иконку в момент смены состояния индикаторов?

Comment: @test123, извините меня, вы бы не могли мне показать  примером с моим кодом уже несколько часов мучаюсь и не могу ни как сделать... извините если наглею я ещё учусь покажите с моим кодом как если не тяжело вам?

Comment: @сергейбабий, То что вы скинули - не показывает что происходит в целом. Либо скиньте весь проект, либо приведите полный код.

Comment: @test123, Дайте свой email или добавьте меня в скайпе sergey21071990 я вам скину проект сюда не хочу просто выкладывать